# Auto date stamp in different columns based on Status column content change

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to track my orders status by placing auto date stamp so that I can know the turn around time for each stages. Can someone help me with the script to automate the same?

There are 4 stages, Received, Packed, Dispatched and Delivered.

For eg:
Column A has order ID, Col B has status (dropdown), Col C has Received Date, Col D has Packed Date, Col E has Dispatched Date and Col F has Delivered Date.

Based on the status selected in Col B, auto date stamp to be placed in the respective date column.

Sample sheet is attached for reference. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yBQRXP-IWTFwcvusBA68PnFUwP51Xmgo7AyXb12aPmE/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the sheet name

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const sA = ["Received","Packed","Dispatched","Delivered"];
  const idx = sA.indexOf(e.value);
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && ~idx) {
    e.range.offset(0 , idx + 1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

My Sheet1 looks like this:

| Order Id | Status | Received Date | Packed Date | Dispatched Date | Delivered Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Received | 8/16/2021 |  |  |  |
|  | Packed |  | 8/16/2021 |  |  |
|  | Dispatched |  |  | 8/16/2021 |  |
|  | Delivered |  |  |  | 8/16/2021 |

Comment: You cannot run this function from the script editor unless you provide the event object to populate e.  This is meant to utilize the onEdit simple trigger which provides an event object which populates the first parameter in the function which in my case is e.